# My CSV is not generated fully due to an empty fetchedstatsarray, but why is my fetchedstatsarray empty?

Tags: ios, swift, csv

I have an app that takes in user input that is stored in core data. To simplify things, I combined 5 strings from the user inputs, separated them with a comma and then this long string is stored in core data as 1 entity. The comma is separating the individual 'strings' is what makes it a CSV. However, when I tried exporting the csv file, I only managed to get the header.

[image]

The two components of code that is involved in this are as follows. The part collecting the strings and combining them:

```
@objc func addAlarmItem(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Item", message: "Please fill in the blanks", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { [unowned self] action in

            //combined string of attributes
            let myStrings: [String] = alertController.textFields!.compactMap { $0.text }
            let myText = myStrings.joined(separator: ",")

            self.save(myText)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)

        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Name of Engineer"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Date of Alarm in DD/MM/YYYY"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Time of Alarm in 24h (eg: 2300)"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Please indicate True/False (type True or False)"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Insert comments (if any), or NIL"
        }

    func save(_ itemName: String) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "AlarmItem", in: managedContext)!
        let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
        item.setValue(itemName, forKey: "alarmAttributes")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            tableView.reloadData()

        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("Failed to save an item", err)
        }
    }
```

And the part that does the exporting core data entry as csv:

```
    @objc func exportCSV(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        exportDatabase()
    }

    func exportDatabase() {
        let exportString = createExportString()
        saveAndExport(exportString: exportString)
    }

    func saveAndExport(exportString: String) {
        let exportFilePath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "itemlist.csv"
        let exportFileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: exportFilePath)
        FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: exportFilePath, contents: NSData() as Data, attributes: nil)
        var fileHandle: FileHandle? = nil

        do {
            fileHandle = try FileHandle(forUpdating: exportFileUrl as URL)
        } catch {
            print("filehandle has error")
        }

        if fileHandle != nil {
            fileHandle!.seekToEndOfFile()
            let csvData = exportString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
            fileHandle!.write(csvData!)
            fileHandle!.closeFile()

            let firstActivityItem = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: exportFilePath)
            let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

            activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
                UIActivity.ActivityType.assignToContact,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFlickr,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.postToVimeo,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.postToTencentWeibo
            ]
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view


 activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection()
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func createExportString() -> String {
        var alarmAttributes: String?
        var export: String = NSLocalizedString("Engineer Name,Date of Alarm,Time of Alarm,True or False,Engineer Comments \n", comment: "")

        for (index, AlarmItem) in fetchedStatsArray.enumerated() {
            if index <= fetchedStatsArray.count - 1 {
                alarmAttributes = AlarmItem.value(forKey: "alarmAttributes") as! String?
                let alarmAttributeStrings = alarmAttributes
                export += "\(alarmAttributeStrings ?? "0") \n"
            }
        }
        print("the app will now print: \(export) ")
        return export
    }
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my fetchedStatsArray is empty . I have attached to entire code in my github.

The full code is located here: https://github.com/danialaqil/TFAApp/blob/master/AlarmChartsApp/HistoryController.swift if you need to see the entire thing in more detail

Comment: Does the `print("the app will now print: \(export) ")` line show more rows?

Comment: it only prints the headers

Comment: Then your `for (index, AlarmItem) in fetchedStatsArray.enumerated()` isn't running because `fetchedStatsArray` is empty. You need to figure out why that array is empty.

Comment: ah good point, I tried to print the fetchedStatsArray and gives out an empty array. Now I have to figure out why it's empty. Which is off because from my code it looks fine, plus the entries I entered into the app stays inside the table view which means the array is being stored somewhere.

Comment: I am still trying to fix it btw so if anyone is reading this and has an idea how to fix it it would be very much appreciated. Thank you so much for those who have helped too

Comment: I see nothing in your code appending to the fetchedStatsArray so it will be hard to help you on that.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with my code either. This is very confusing haha thanks for looking anyway